# Are type, constant/static/global, and pointer prefixes still necessary in C coding standards, considering the capabilities of modern IDEs?

Tags: c, coding-style, coding-standards

Our coding standards for C include various prefixes for data types, constants, static/global variables, and pointers. These prefixes were originally introduced for code review purposes, but with the convenience of modern IDEs, which provide type information through highlighting, we are questioning whether it is still a best practice to use these prefixes in variable and type names. Additionally, the accumulation of prefixes for pointers can make naming confusing and affect the order of elements in variable names. What are your thoughts on the continued relevance of these prefixes in C programming standards?

Comment: Very few people think those are relevant any more.

Comment: Hungarian notation is pretty irrelevant, but putting the library name into every symbol name remains important if that symbol has "linkage" (is not static). Otherwise, there might be name collisions.

Comment: Not the Hungarian notation question itself but the answers and the discussion might be relevant.